# Unable to access List using web reference in Sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

I want to develop an application in C# which can access sharepoint data without any dependency to Windows Server Machine (Without using sharepoint dll).  After adding reference to project I am unable to use this reference.

For example Web Reference name is: "MyServer".  I am unable to use:

```
MyServer.Lists listService = new MyServer.Lists();
```

Showing error :

> The type or namespace name 'MyServer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the problem is that you have added a "service reference", not a SOAP web service web reference (see this article: http://alexduggleby.com/2008/08/24/add-web-reference-instead-of-service-reference-in-visual-studio-2008/)